# How to remove extra space from all sides in container

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
leading: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Icon(
            Icons.account_circle_rounded,
            size: 58,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 1,
          ),
          Icon(size: 30, Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

i want to remove extra space from container where i placed two icons the one is profile and second is arrow icon
[Here is the image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIiz0.png)

Comment: I didn't look too much into it.. but if You have a 58px circle inside a 30px radius, wouldn't you expect a 1px border? have you tried setting the Icon size to 60px?

Comment: Are you taking about space between those 2 icons and edge of container or space between  2 icons?